Why my message won't get packed correctly as Raw Ethernet packet?
Here is the definition of my message in C (message.h):
    #ifndef MESSAGE_H
    #define MESSAGE_H
    
    #include <stdint.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>
    #include <assert.h>
    
    #ifndef __GNUC__
    #error Requires GCC bit field packing.
    #endif
    #ifdef BITS_BIG_ENDIAN
    #error Requires bit fields to be packed little-endian (LSB first)
    #endif
    
    // Definitions for AXI-related types
    typedef enum {
        OK = 0,
        SLAVE_ERROR = 2,
        DECODE_ERROR = 3,
        PREVIOUS_ERROR_PROPAGATED = 4,
        UNSUPPORTED_TRANSACTION = 5
    } AXIResponse;
    
    typedef enum {
        FIXED_ADDRESS = 0,
        INCREMENT_ADDRESS = 1
    } AXIBurst;
    
    typedef enum {
        BYTE = 0,
        HALFWORD = 1,
        WORD = 2
    } AXISize;
    
    // Define the message with headers and a flexible array member for payload
    typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
        uint8_t isWrite : 1;
        uint8_t isResponse : 1;
        uint8_t reserved : 2;
        uint8_t responseStatus : 4;
        uint8_t payloadType : 8;
        uint8_t burstType : 2;
        uint8_t size : 3;
        uint16_t length : 11; // Number of 32-bit integers in the payload
    } TransactionHeader1;
    static_assert(sizeof(TransactionHeader1) == 4, "TransactionHeader1 not packed");
    
    typedef struct {
        uint32_t memoryAddress;
    } TransactionHeader2;
    static_assert(sizeof(TransactionHeader2) == 4, "TransactionHeader2 not packed");
    
    typedef struct {
        TransactionHeader1 header1;
        TransactionHeader2 header2;
        uint32_t payload[]; // Flexible array member for payload
    } Message;
    
    // Declarations for functions used to manage messages
    Message *createMessage(bool isWrite, bool isResponse,
                           AXIResponse responseStatus, uint8_t payloadType,
                           AXIBurst burstType, AXISize size, uint16_t length,
                           uint32_t memoryAddress, const uint32_t *payload);
    void freeMessage(Message *msg);
    uint16_t getSize(const Message *msg);
    
    #endif // MESSAGE_H

Also, my message.c:
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
    #include "message.h"
    
    #define MIN_PAYLOAD_SIZE 46
    
    Message *createMessage(bool isWrite, bool isResponse,
                           AXIResponse responseStatus, uint8_t payloadType,
                           AXIBurst burstType, AXISize size, uint16_t length,
                           uint32_t memoryAddress, const uint32_t *payload) {
        // Calculate actual payload size in bytes
        uint16_t payloadSizeBytes = length * sizeof(uint32_t);
        // Make sure minimum payload size in bytes is reserved
        uint16_t allocatedPayloadSize = (payloadSizeBytes < MIN_PAYLOAD_SIZE) ? MIN_PAYLOAD_SIZE : payloadSizeBytes;
    
        Message *msg = (Message *)malloc(sizeof(TransactionHeader1) + sizeof(TransactionHeader2) + allocatedPayloadSize);
        if (!msg) {
            // Handle allocation failure (e.g., by returning NULL or handling error)
            return NULL;
        }
    
        msg->header1.isWrite = isWrite;
        msg->header1.isResponse = isResponse;
        msg->header1.reserved = 0;
        msg->header1.responseStatus = (uint8_t)responseStatus;
        msg->header1.payloadType = payloadType;
        msg->header1.burstType = (uint8_t)burstType;
        msg->header1.size = (uint8_t)size;
        msg->header1.length = length; // Assuming this is the number of 32-bit integers in the payload
        msg->header2.memoryAddress = memoryAddress;
    
        // Copy only the valid payload bytes
        memcpy(msg->payload, payload, payloadSizeBytes);
        
        // Pad remaining space with zeros if necessary
        if (payloadSizeBytes < MIN_PAYLOAD_SIZE) {
            memset((uint8_t*)msg->payload + payloadSizeBytes, 0, MIN_PAYLOAD_SIZE - payloadSizeBytes);
        }
        
        return msg;
    }
    
    void freeMessage(Message *msg) {
        free(msg);
    }
    
    uint16_t getSize(const Message *msg) {
        // Calculate actual payload size in bytes
        uint16_t payloadSizeBytes = msg->header1.length * sizeof(uint32_t);
        // Make sure minimum payload size in bytes is reserved
        uint16_t allocatedPayloadSize = (payloadSizeBytes < MIN_PAYLOAD_SIZE) ? MIN_PAYLOAD_SIZE : payloadSizeBytes;
        uint16_t msgSize = sizeof(TransactionHeader1) + sizeof(TransactionHeader2) + allocatedPayloadSize;
        return msgSize;
    }

and finally (main.c):
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <sys/ioctl.h>
    #include <net/if.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <netinet/if_ether.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <netpacket/packet.h>
    #include "message.h"
    
    #define ETHER_TYPE 0x9000 // Loopback
    
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        if (argc != 3) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <interface> <destination MAC>\n", argv[0]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        const char* interface_name = argv[1];
        const char* dst_mac_str = argv[2];
    
        int sockfd;
        struct ifreq if_idx;
        struct ifreq if_mac;
        struct sockaddr_ll socket_address;
        uint8_t dst_mac[6];
        Message* msg;
        uint8_t* frame;
        size_t frame_length;
    
        // Open RAW socket to send on
        if ((sockfd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL))) == -1) {
            perror("socket");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        // Get the index of the interface to send on
        memset(&if_idx, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
        strncpy(if_idx.ifr_name, interface_name, IFNAMSIZ-1);
        if (ioctl(sockfd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &if_idx) < 0) {
            perror("SIOCGIFINDEX");
            close(sockfd);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        // Get the MAC address of the interface to send on
        memset(&if_mac, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
        strncpy(if_mac.ifr_name, interface_name, IFNAMSIZ-1);
        if (ioctl(sockfd, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &if_mac) < 0) {
            perror("SIOCGIFHWADDR");
            close(sockfd);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        // Convert destination MAC address from string to byte array
        sscanf(dst_mac_str, "%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx",
               &dst_mac[0], &dst_mac[1], &dst_mac[2],
               &dst_mac[3], &dst_mac[4], &dst_mac[5]);
    
        // Create a message
        // For simplicity, we are using hardcoded values for the payload and other parameters
        uint32_t payload_data[] = {0xDEADBEEF, 0xCAFEBABE};
        msg = createMessage(false, false, OK, 0x01, INCREMENT_ADDRESS, WORD, 2, 0x00400000, payload_data);
    
        // Calculate the total frame length
        frame_length = sizeof(struct ether_header) + getSize(msg);
        frame = malloc(frame_length);
    
        if (!frame) {
            perror("malloc");
            freeMessage(msg);
            close(sockfd);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        // Construct Ethernet header
        struct ether_header *eh = (struct ether_header *) frame;
        // Use the actual hardware MAC address here
        memcpy(eh->ether_shost, if_mac.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data, ETH_ALEN);
        memcpy(eh->ether_dhost, dst_mac, ETH_ALEN);
        eh->ether_type = htons(ETHER_TYPE);
    
        // Copy message after Ethernet header
        memcpy(frame + sizeof(struct ether_header), msg, getSize(msg));
    
        // Index of the network device
        socket_address.sll_ifindex = if_idx.ifr_ifindex;
        socket_address.sll_halen = ETH_ALEN;
        memcpy(socket_address.sll_addr, dst_mac, ETH_ALEN);
    
        // Send packet
        if (sendto(sockfd, frame, frame_length, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&socket_address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll)) < 0) {
            perror("send");
        } else {
            printf("Raw Ethernet packet sent\n");
        }
    
        // Cleanup
        free(frame);
        freeMessage(msg);
        close(sockfd);
    
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

The output of the tcpdump is this:
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on enp4s0f2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
02:52:51.433953 Loopback, skipCount 256 (invalid)
    0x0000:  0001 4900 0000 4000 efbe adde beba feca  ..I...@.........
    0x0010:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
    0x0020:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
    0x0030:  0000 0000 0000                           ......

Clearly the TransactionHeader1 and TransactionHeader2 are not assembled correctly which is very puzzling to me. I appreciate any help.

Please clarify where exactly the result deviates from your expectations.

What compiler?  What OS?  What endianness?  And bit-fields are HORRIBLE for portable serialization: "An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit- field. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains, whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined.

(cont) The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined."

@AndrewHenle OP says in the code this only works with gcc and little endian so your tirade is misplaced. This question is not about portability.

@stark GCC supports fifty eight different hardware architectures  Saying "GCC" and "little endian" is pretty useless in specifying things like platform ABIs that determine where bits go.  When you need to specify exactly where bits need to be when serialized, it's ALWAYS about portability.

dataheader1(0001 4900): isWrite=0 isResponse=0 responseStatus=0 payloadType=1 burstType=1 size=2 length=2, dataheader2(0000 4000): address=0x00400000, data3( efbe adde beba feca): payload={0xdeadbeef, 0xcafebabe} correspond to your data. Tcpdump dissector expected 'skipcount and function' in the first 4octets (counting in the output). I'd tag along to the first comment: What were your expectations there?

In some apps the byte alignment of structures is very critical.  Please explore the #pragma pack preprocessor directive and see/consider if it has any relevancy to your application.  Specifically, a byte alignment of 1 often cures many ills ...  but saying this is a horrible and crude summary of the topic.

@yvs2014 I’m expecting what you described. How did you find this? Could you elaborate a bit more?

Putting off endianness: "0001 4900" first byte (00) is "isWrite=0 isResponse=0 responseStatus=0", the second (01) is "payloadType=1", the next (49) is "length(2)<<5 + size(2)<<2 + burstType(1)". The rest is just your data with swapped bytes according to the used endianness. P.s. in that tcpdump output: srcmac,destmac and type(0x9000) are skipped, taking them into account at numbering: 15,16,17,18th bytes were taken by tcpdump dissector as a wrong skipcount=0x100(256) and an unknown function=0x49(73).
